# What is the use of companion object in kotlin and replacement in java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

```
companion object {
    var funAfterPermission: (() -> Unit)? = null
}
```

What is the use of companion object in the above snippet and what is the meaning of line

```
 var funAfterPermission: (() -> Unit)? = null
```

Comment: in java(7) it will be `class Outer { static interface IDoAfterPermission { void do(); }
public static IDoAfterPermission funAfterPermission; }` and usage `Outer.funAfterPermission.do();` instead `Outer.funAfterPermission()` in Kotlin

Answer (score 1):

Your line means that there's a var with the name `funAfterPermission` which accepts a function ([high order functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)) as parameter which returns the equivalent to void in java It acceps a method with no parameters. The var itself is null by default and can be null.

```
var funAfterPermission: (() -> Unit)? = null
```

Example:

```
fun test(): (() -> Unit)? {
        println("test")
        return null
}

funAfterPermission = test()
```

Its like an [eval](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/eval.html) in several languages. It calls something in another function but doesnt assign anything since it returns Unit.

[companion objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects) are used to get the "static" behaviour from java. You can access your funAfterPermission using `YourClass.funAfterPermission = ....`

Comment: Why we use this? Can you explain it in another way i didn't get.

Comment: You should not use that. But you can use that you have a value assigned to a variable which get its value from a function (high order functions

Comment: Emanuel, don't mix [Unit](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/index.html) with [Nothing](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html), they are not the same.

Comment: Thankyou sooooo mucchh

Answer (score 1):

`companion object` is the replacement for singleton in Java.

`() -> Unit` represent a delegate. It can be divide into `()` and `Unit`. `()` means the delegate should accept nothing as parameter. `Unit`  means the delegate return nothing (same as void in Java). Combining them means it is a delegate that does not require  any parameters and does not return anything.

`(() -> Unit)?` means the delegate can be null.

For example, `(Int, String) -> String` means it requires the first parameter to be `Int`, the second parameter to be `String` and it returns `String`.

```
class Foo {
    var greeting: () -> Unit = this::helloWorld
    fun helloWorld() {

    }
    fun hello() {
        greeting()
    }
}
```

Delegate is assigned by `::` syntax and can be called like a normal function.